# Dates For Events Not Mentioned in the Martian book/movie

Tags: the-martian, andy-weir

I know the original dates etc for the Ares III mission because of the movie promo stuff [image]
but when their plans got messed up because of Watney being left behind  does anyone know the dates (even rough dates or a month will do) of:

- When they rescued Watney
- When they actually got back to earth
- When that movie Beck/Beth baby scene
- When the Mark Watney teacher scene was.
- The time it takes to get from Mars to Earth in the Hermes

Comment: In the book Watney's rescue happens on "Mission Day 687" (or the preceding day, whatever), so one can get the first day of the mission and add to that.

Comment: Using this method if they left on 7th Nov 2035 they rescued Mark on Thursday, 24th September 2037. Now I just need to know how long a journey from Mars to Earth in the Hermes is and I'm golden.

Comment: Well I found on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khIHZp_GTEI) that it took 211 days to get back to Earth so I'll stick with that.

Answer (score 3):

Mark would have been rescued on Mission Day 687 as stated in the book which is Thursday, 24th September 2037.

According to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khIHZp_GTEI) it then took 211 days to get from Mars orbit to Earth in the Hermes so Friday, 23rd April 2038 was when they got back.